# Output of card shuffle using arraylists not displaying

Tags: java, arraylist, shuffle

Everything works here except trying to show the Deck after I shuffle it. I'm not sure why, but the arraylist seems to be empty after shuffling. If I comment out the shuffling code, the Deck displays, but unshuffled, obviously. Since this is an assignment, I need my program to stay in the same general format, and the algorithm for shuffling needs to remain the same as much as possible.

```
public class Shuffler
{
    public static void selectionShuffle(ArrayList<Card> values) {
    ArrayList<Card> shuffled = new ArrayList<Card>();
    ArrayList<Card> copy = new ArrayList<Card>();
    for (int k = 51; k >= 0;) {
        int r = (int)(Math.random() * (double)52);
        if (r < values.size()) {
            shuffled.add(values.get(r));
            values.remove(r);
            k--;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        values.set(i, shuffled.get(i));
    }


}
```

Here is the Deck Constructor, it creates a deck out of three arrays to form three card objects.

```
public class Deck
{
    public static ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    private int size;
    public Deck(String[] ranks, String[] suits, int[] values) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            cards.add(new Card(ranks[i], suits[i], values[i]));
        }
        size = values.length;
        shuffle();
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        Shuffler.selectionShuffle(cards);
        size = size();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the "copy" variable for?

Comment: Junk. I was testing last night and forgot to remove the garbage before positng in a rush this morning.

Comment: Consider using Random.nextInt() for your random index generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < shuffled.size(); i++) {
    values.add(shuffled.get(i));
}
```

Problem is you had:

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
    values.set(i, shuffled.get(i));
}
```

The size of values at this point is 0 so it won't do anything...You removed all elements from values so it will have size 0.

Comment: ... what a silly mistake. You're right. I also had to change values.set(i, shuffled.get(i)) to value.add(shuffled.get(i)). Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Java passes object by reference, meaning that if your function is manilupating changed object, it will also be changed after function call.

Here you call `selectionShuffle`:

```
public void shuffle() {
    Shuffler.selectionShuffle(cards);
    size = size();
}
```

And the `selectionShuffle` function manipulates passed list `cards`. Because you call `values.remove(r);`, your list is is empty when function finishes.

A simple solution would be to create a copy of passed `values` and manipulate the copy. The `ArrayList` has a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection)) to do this.